# Update specific list of packages with yum

Tags: centos, centos7, yum, update, stability

As most company we have different pre-production environment: development, integration, staging, production.
We would like to keep these env OS updated but we would like to perform yum update in development, after a couple of days update the exact list of package that has been updated on integration env, after a couple of days in staging, and finally in production.
The purpose is to avoid that a new update will pop up during the process and have it running in production at first.
As far as I googled, there is no something like 'yum update at this timestamp'
Do you know if there is some way to handle this? Asking since we have to deal with mission critical environment.
Thx

Comment: You could do this by maintaining your own repository mirror(s), which is quite simple, and `rsync` them at the correct intervals.

Answer (score 3):

I am doing Enterprise Linux based on RHEL CentOS for almost 20 years.

- What you need is a (snapshot) clone of a repository.
- Then you can ensure all servers (qa, prod) have exactly the same versions

Problem is that the reposities are changing (with updates) and you want to avoid that, right?

In enterprise environments, redhat network or satellite is used to manage the packages against group of servers.

The opensource version of satellite is called spacewalk, you can find it here
[Spacewalk install documentation](https://github.com/spacewalkproject/spacewalk/wiki/HowToInstall)

Maybe you can go with a vault for smaller environments, this are time based snapshots of repositories:
https://vault.centos.org/

I hope this helps
BR Chris